# How to substitute values to a conf file using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that has created a file (`/tmp/values.txt`) in each server with the following content

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
5.5.5.5
```

And I have a conf file named `etcd.conf` in the `/tmp/etcd.conf` with the following content

and I need to substitute the value  of each line from `/tmp/values.txt`, so  `/tmp/etcd.conf` will look like this:

```
SELF_IP=1.1.1.1
NODE_1_IP=2.2.2.2
NODE_2_IP=3.3.3.3
NODE_3_IP=4.4.4.4
NODE_4_IP=5.5.5.5
```

Is there a way I can do this? I used the following `lookup` method but it only works in the controll server

```
    - name: Create etcd.conf
      template:
        src: etcd.conf.j2
        dest: /tmp/etcd.conf
      vars:
        my_values: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/values.txt').split('\n') }}"
        my_vars: [SELF_IP, NODE_1_IP, NODE_2_IP, NODE_3_IP, NODE_4_IP]
        my_dict: "{{ dict(my_vars|zip(my_values)) }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`slurp:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/slurp_module.html) task to grab the content for each machine, or use `command: cat /tmp/values.txt` and then examine the `stdout_lines` of its `register:`-ed variable to achieve that same `.split("\n")` behavior (I believe you'll still need to use that `.split` call after `| b64decode` if you use the `slurp` approach)

What will likely require some massaging is that you'll need to identify the group (which may very well include `all`) of inventory hostnames for which that command will produce content, and then grab the hostvar out of them to get all values

Conceptually, similar to `[ hostvars[hv].tmp_values.stdout_lines for hv in groups[the_group] ] | join("\n")`, but it'll be tedious to write out, so I'd only want to do that if you aren't able to get it to work on your own